# How to script SPARQL permissions grants in Virtuoso

Tags: permissions, sparql, sql-grant, virtuoso

I need to grant permissions, load RDF data and insert, modify and delete some of the triples, in script (not interactively through Virtuoso Conductor).

I grant permissions for Virtuoso version **7.1.0.3207**, and  it worked fine:

```
isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_MODIFY_BY_DICT_CONTENTS to \"SPARQL\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_MODIFY_BY_DICT_CONTENTS to \"SPARQL_UPDATE\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_DELETE_DICT_CONTENT to \"SPARQL\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_DELETE_DICT_CONTENT to \"SPARQL_UPDATE\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_INSERT_DICT_CONTENT to \"SPARQL\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_INSERT_DICT_CONTENT to \"SPARQL_UPDATE\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.L_O_LOOK to \"SPARQL\";"

isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant execute on DB.DBA.L_O_LOOK to \"SPARQL_UPDATE\";"
```

But It seems not working for version **7.2.4.2.3217**
I got error message by deleting triples.

> `Virtuoso 42000 Error CL...:SECURITY: No SPARQL_UPDATE permission to use RDF loader`

How can I solve this problem? please help.

Thanks, Yan

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information here, I think this may solve your issue --

```
 isql VERBOSE=$VERB ERRORS=stdout ECHO=$VERB "exec=grant SPARQL_UPDATE to \"SPARQL\";"
```

If not, you may get a faster response (for Open Source Edition) through the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), or (for Commercial Edition and/or VOS Support Contract) through an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is to grant privileges on delete also:

```
grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_DELETE_DICT_CONTENT to "SPARQL";
```

Comment: In another case `grant "SPARQL_UPDATE" to "SPARQL"` was the solution.